# spring mvc unable to map url

Tags: spring-mvc, url, resources, mapping

My dispatcher servlet is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springimplant.mvc.controllers"/>

</beans>
```

I have a home controller under the namespace Home controller as follows

```
    package com.springimplant.mvc.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String goHome()
    {
        return "Welcome Home";
    }
}
```

Web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>course-project</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListner</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Still when I run the application in localhost I am getting a 404 error as
"The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."
Kindly Guide where I am going wrong

The url I am hitting is 
http://localhost:8080/course-project/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was trying to post that string as ResponseBody only.
Here is what worked for me I started with a fresh project with following changes

1. Downloaded STS(Spring Tool Suite) again(my console debugging log was not showing up).
2. Used Tomcat 8.5 instead of pivotal TC server 4.0 you can try pivotal TC 3.2-3.5 which is based on same.
3. Dynamic Web Module Facet I was using 4.0 I degraded it to 3.1.(I saw somewhere that 4.0 supports @RestController annotation rather than @Controller annotation)
4. I was using slf4j-log4j13 facet and log4j implementation this was giving an error sth like class not found "log.logger".So I added another facet "log4j-simple".

Though I still have clue what out of these worked for me :)
Thanks for your responses.
Here it is on github
https://github.com/gauravmatta/springmvc/tree/master/my-project

Answer (score 0):

Please remove @ResponseBody, as dispatcher servlet should understand that the returning value is not a HTTP Response rather it is a view name. And also please make sure that the returning value should be same as your view page name.